# How does resuming downloads work?

Tags: http, web, networking, file-handling, http-request

I have seen download managers manage to resume HTTP downloads from where they stopped. How are they able to resume downloads? Is it related to the `Accept-Range` Header? Or are there other mechanisms that download managers use to identify how much of the file has been downloaded and how much is left to be downloaded?

Comment: Hi :) welcome to SE.SE :) i think your question is a much better fit for stackoverflow, though

Comment: @marstato they'll probably call it too vague on StackOverflow though. Pretty sure they usually want one specific question with one specific answer on there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with software engineering.

Comment: @Philipp: arguably, this can be seen as an algorithmic question, and algorithmic questions are definitely on-topic on this site. Of course, most questions of the type "how does XYZ type software work" are too broad for this site. However, I think in this case, it is unlikely there are a lot of different approaches for resuming a download - let me try to reword the question a bit.

Answer (score 5):

For tracking the progress: the response to the first download request will have a [`Content-Length` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length) telling the download manager how big the entire file is. That info will be persisted (and obviously shown in the UI).
Finding out How much has been downloaded is a simple matter of asking the OS how big the local file is.

On pause/resume: Yes, this is done with the [`Range` request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range). I don't know how many servers that support the request-header advertise that support with the [`Accept-Ranges` response-header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Ranges).
If you resume a download from a server that does not support the `Range` header, download managers will typically download the content again, possibly not writing the bytes to disk that they already have (because that avoids unnecessary load on the disk).